# Understanding Cross Origin Resource Sharing

Tags: php, cors

I understand what is CORS theoretical, but to allow such behavior what step should I do/implement on client side and server side(PHP or Apache).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client side you don't have to do anything.

On server side you have to add 2 headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

you can do it in `php` or better on web-server level, in your case `apache`.

Comment: Can I set this rule for specific routes?

Comment: @justsomedev Yes, you can if you need.